# How to assign different functions for each button clicked in a for loop using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an button which is suppose to update records in the database.
All users info are gotten using the while loop in php, but the issue is that when I try updating each user, only the first record updates.

This is my code

```
<input type="number" id="advertiserId" >
<input type="button" value="Update" class="updateAdvertiser"></td>
```

```js
<script>
var update =document.getElementsByClassName("updateAdvertiser") ;
for (var i = 0; i < update.length; i++) { 
$(update[i]).on("click", function() {
            var advertiserId=$("#advertiserId").val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "update.php", 
            type: "POST", 
            async: false, 
            data: {
            "advertiserid" : advertiserId, 
        }, 
            success: function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
       }
    });
  }) 
}

</script>
```

The advertiserid is in a while loop
The above script only updates the first record in the database.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be enough information for us to help. Where is `id` coming from? What does the HTML look like? What's the issue?

Comment: I have just updated my question. The id is coming from an input field with id userid

Comment: Please include a working example of your issue here so we can reproduce it and help you fix it

Comment: Element ID's must be unique. So `var id=$("#userid").val()` will always return the first  one. If you have one per user here need html sample to help more

Comment: Html you posted has no class `"updateAdvertiser"` as in the js. Not enough shown regarding the parents that input is in

Comment: I have updated my post now

Comment: Also never ever use `async:false`. It is a horrible practice and was deprecated by browser vendors years ago. Should be seeing a deprecation warning in dev tools console when you use it

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from the `</td>` this is in a table.

Change the repeating id to class and then traverse from the specific button clicked to the corresponding input , targeting it by className , to get the the value.

Note that no additional loop required. Following works on all of them.

```js
$('input.updateAdvertiser').on('click', function(){
    const id = $(this).siblings('.advertiserId').val()
    console.log('ID =', id)
    // do ajax
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Sues Cool Company</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="advertiserId" value="30">
      <input type="button" value="Update" class="updateAdvertiser">
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Bill's Emporium</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="advertiserId" value="10">
      <input type="button" value="Update" class="updateAdvertiser">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

to make it simple you will need to write a function that will execute directly your javascript code and you will call it directly in the button in your HTML code in the php loop like this :

```
<script>
function updating(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
            "id" : id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#response").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then you call it as follows in the button at the HTML level in your php loop:

```
<button onclick="updating('<?php echo user_id; ?>')" />
```

NB: Be sure to replace user_id by what represents the user id in the php loop.